# Graph API mobileApp install Summary alternative API was pushed as reports

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, intune, microsoft-graph-intune

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/reports/getAppStatusOverviewReport
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/reports/getDeviceInstallStatusReport

these calls are not working though these are the new endpoints.
but the previous extension https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/mobileDevices till here it is fetching the data but after that user status or install status is not working.

I am getting this error.
OData Version: 4, Error: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. (No OData route exists that match template ~/singleton/navigation with http verb GET for request /ReportingService/StatelessReportingFEService/deviceManagement/reports.)
OData Version: 3, Error: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. (No OData route exists that match template ~/singleton/navigation with http verb GET for request /ReportingService/StatelessReportingFEService/deviceManagement/reports.)
Details:
DataSourceKind=OData
DataSourcePath=https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/reports

Answer (score 0):

What are you supplying as your request body?  For example, the getAppStatusOverviewReport should have a request body such as:

Method - POST
Request body - {"filter":"(ApplicationId eq '16a2c0c9-17c9-4f57-8f33-39a800e69a21')"}